# Monitor http connections

Tags: linux, http, monitor, connection

I am looking for tool on ubuntu i.e. netdata, with graph or not, which can monitoring live traffic on connections http, i mean exactly site on my webpage. It's not enough to IP and port, but complete site address - a connections to live hls stream. I'll be gratefull if I could see how many connections in meantime are connected to specific stream, hls file, place on server. Thanks for ANY help!

Comment: It could be specific to the HTTP server you are using. BTW you could spell out [HTTP Live Streaming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Live_Streaming) instead of lowercase hls

Comment: Yeah, you also have a right, but there is many external tools which are watching on connections, I won't monitor exactly in my http server (it is nginx) but in example tcpdump can show incoming requests on specific ip and port, so I have in mind similar tool, if that even exists. Thank you, howewer.

Comment: Isn't an evaluation of the http servers access log files enough for this?

Comment: Yes, exactly but I need a tool which show in real time data what I choose. I found ngxtop!

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.